# How to insert hyphen after third character

Tags: regex

I want to remove the first three characters of the string and insert a hyphen between 3rd and 4th of the remaining 6 characters.
For example
Input:

```
123456789
```

Output:

```
456-789
```

My regular expression removes the first three characters, but I'm not sure how to insert hyphen.

```
(^.{3})(\w+) $2
```

Comment: `/(\d{3})(\d*)/$1-$2/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^.{3}(.{3})(.*)
```

replace with:

```
$1-$2
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/uR7wI6/1)

Comment: `^...(...)(.*)` would be shorter :)

Comment: @ndn,Thank you very much

Comment: @ndnenkov Special Thanks for link